# Provide different functionality for different logged in users in android application through same login screen

Tags: android

I have same login page for two users in my android application. Based on logged in user types I need to provide  functionality. How to form the code structure for this ?

Comment: `How to form the code structure for this` there is no correct answer for this question. Only opinions can be.

Answer (score 0):

Oh this is very simple, you can do this using below logic in login screen.

```
if(login == true){
        switch (loginType){
            case typeOne:
                // provide specific functionality for login type 'one'
                break;
            case tryTwo:
                // provide specific functionality for login type 'two'
                break;
        }
    }
```